# `cannot resolve module` compilation errors after downgrading the Ballerina version

Tags: dependencies, version, ballerina, downgrade

I installed Ballerina Swan Lake 2201.7.2 and created a new Ballerina package using `bal new hello` command. The `main.bal` file contained the following code.

```php
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    io:println("Hello, World!");
}
```

`Ballerina.toml` file content was as follows.

```ini
[package]
org = "demo"
name = "hello"
version = "0.1.0"
distribution = "2201.7.2"

[build-options]
observabilityIncluded = true
```

Then I ran the `bal run` command and it gave the output successfully.

```
Compiling source
        demo/hello:0.1.0

Running executable

Hello, World!
```

Then I changed my Ballerina Swan Lake version to `2201.6.1` using the `bal dist use 2201.6.1` command.

After that, to compile and run the package with Ballerina Swan Lake version `2201.6.1`, I used the `bal run` command. But it gave the following error.

```
Compiling source
        demo/hello:0.1.0
ERROR [main.bal:(1:1,1:21)] cannot resolve module 'ballerina/io'
ERROR [main.bal:(4:5,4:32)] undefined function 'println'
ERROR [main.bal:(4:5,4:32)] undefined module 'io'
error: compilation contains errors
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Ballerina guarantees is that it will continue to support compiling packages using a higher Ballerina version that were already compiled with a lower Ballerina version, given that there are no backward incompatible changes introduced with the new releases. (Usually when there are backward incompatible changes, they are mentioned in the release note.)

There is no guarantee that the Ballerina packages compiled with a higher version of Ballerina will compile with a lower version of Ballerina due to the incompatible dependencies used by the package. For example, the above scenario can be explained as follows.

When compiling the program using Ballerina version `2201.7.2`, it creates the `Dependencies.toml` file which contains the following.

```ini
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE. DO NOT MODIFY.

# This file is auto-generated by Ballerina for managing dependency versions.
# It should not be modified by hand.

[ballerina]
dependencies-toml-version = "2"
distribution-version = "2201.7.2"

[[package]]
org = "ballerina"
name = "io"
version = "1.5.0"
dependencies = [
    {org = "ballerina", name = "jballerina.java"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "lang.value"}
]
modules = [
    {org = "ballerina", packageName = "io", moduleName = "io"}
]

[[package]]
org = "ballerina"
name = "jballerina.java"
version = "0.0.0"

[[package]]
org = "ballerina"
name = "lang.value"
version = "0.0.0"
dependencies = [
    {org = "ballerina", name = "jballerina.java"}
]

[[package]]
org = "ballerina"
name = "observe"
version = "1.1.0"
dependencies = [
    {org = "ballerina", name = "jballerina.java"}
]

[[package]]
org = "ballerinai"
name = "observe"
version = "0.0.0"
dependencies = [
    {org = "ballerina", name = "jballerina.java"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "observe"}
]
modules = [
    {org = "ballerinai", packageName = "observe", moduleName = "observe"}
]

[[package]]
org = "demo"
name = "hello"
version = "0.1.0"
dependencies = [
    {org = "ballerina", name = "io"},
    {org = "ballerinai", name = "observe"}
]
modules = [
    {org = "demo", packageName = "hello", moduleName = "hello"}
]
```

It shows the Ballerina package's dependencies and their minimum supported versions. For example, here Ballerina version `2201.7.2` requires at least `io` version `1.5.0`.

When the package is then compiled with Ballerina version `2201.6.1`, it reads this `Dependencies.toml` file and check whether this `io` module version is supported by Ballerina version `2201.6.1`. When it doesn't it throws the above `cannot resolve module  'ballerina/io'` error.

As a remedy, what you can do is deleting the `Dependecies.toml` file created by the Ballerina version `2201.7.2`, and compile the package using the version `2201.6.1`. Then it will run the compile and run the code without any errors.

```
Compiling source
        demo/hello:0.1.0

Running executable

Hello, World!
```

You can also see the below `Dependencies.toml` file created with the version `2201.6.1` which says the Ballerina version requires at least `io` version `1.4.1`. While `io` version `1.4.1` falls within the compatible `io` version ranges supported by the Ballerina version `2201.6.1`, `io` version `1.5.0` is not supported by the Ballerina version `2201.6.1`. That's why the previous error occurred.

```ini
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE. DO NOT MODIFY.

# This file is auto-generated by Ballerina for managing dependency versions.
# It should not be modified by hand.

[ballerina]
dependencies-toml-version = "2"
distribution-version = "2201.6.1"

[[package]]
org = "ballerina"
name = "io"
version = "1.4.1"
dependencies = [
    {org = "ballerina", name = "jballerina.java"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "lang.value"}
]
modules = [
    {org = "ballerina", packageName = "io", moduleName = "io"}
]

[[package]]
org = "ballerina"
name = "jballerina.java"
version = "0.0.0"

[[package]]
org = "ballerina"
name = "lang.value"
version = "0.0.0"
dependencies = [
    {org = "ballerina", name = "jballerina.java"}
]

[[package]]
org = "ballerina"
name = "observe"
version = "1.0.7"
dependencies = [
    {org = "ballerina", name = "jballerina.java"}
]

[[package]]
org = "ballerinai"
name = "observe"
version = "0.0.0"
dependencies = [
    {org = "ballerina", name = "jballerina.java"},
    {org = "ballerina", name = "observe"}
]
modules = [
    {org = "ballerinai", packageName = "observe", moduleName = "observe"}
]

[[package]]
org = "demo"
name = "hello"
version = "0.1.0"
dependencies = [
    {org = "ballerina", name = "io"},
    {org = "ballerinai", name = "observe"}
]
modules = [
    {org = "demo", packageName = "hello", moduleName = "hello"}
]
```